# group_by a list of items which have many tags in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, grouping

I have a list of objects which could have 0 or more tags associated with them. In the simplest scenario I have this a hash of objects and a list of tags:

```
collection = {'object1': ['tag1', 'tag2'], 'object2': ['tag1'], 'object3
': ['tag2'], 'object4': []}
```

So each object could have many tags.

I want to group_by each tag and return this:

```
{'tag1': ['object1', 'object2'], 'tag2': ['object1, 'object3'], nil: ['object4']}
```

(I don't mind if we use nil or empty string or whatever object modelizes "no tags")

Comment: Is this data from a database?  This looks like a left join between two tables.

Comment: No. It is not from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below:

```
collection = {'object1': ['tag1', 'tag2'], 'object2': ['tag1'], 'object3': ['tag2'], 'object4': []}
result = {}
collection.map do |object, tags|
  if tags.any?
    tags.each { |tag| result[tag] ||= []; result[tag] << object }
  else
    result[nil] ||= []; result[nil] << object
  end
end
```

The should result in:

```
2.6.3 :147 > result
 => {"tag1"=>[:object1, :object2], "tag2"=>[:object1, :object3], nil=>[:object4]}
```

Comment: So we can't do with `group_by` method?

Answer (score 1):

```
collection = {
  'object1': ['tag1', 'tag2'], 'object2': ['tag1'], 'object3': ['tag2'],
  'object4': []
}
  #=> {:object1=>["tag1", "tag2"], :object2=>["tag1"], :object3=>["tag2"],
  #    :object4=>[]}
```

I would say the two most Ruby-like ways of doing that are as follows.

**#1**

```
collection.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),h|
  v = [nil] if v.empty?
  v.each { |s| (h[s] ||= []) << k }
end
  #=> {"tag1"=>[:object1, :object2], "tag2"=>[:object1, :object3], nil=>[:object4]}
```

The line

```
(h[s] ||= []) << k
```

expands to

```
(h[s] = h[s] || []) << k
```

so if `h` does not have a key `s` this becomes

```
(h[s] = nil || []) << k
(h[s] = []) << k
h[s] = [k]
```

**#2**

```
collection.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |(k,v),h|
  v = [nil] if v.empty?
  v.each { |s| h[s] << k }
end
  #=> {"tag1"=>[:object1, :object2], "tag2"=>[:object1, :object3], nil=>[:object4]}
```

This uses the third form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that creates a *default proc*. If

```
h = Hash.new(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
```

and `h` does not have a key `k`,

```
h[k] << v
```

causes the the block to be executed, after which `h[k] #=> []`, then the statement

```
h[k] << v
```

is completed.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
  results = Hash.new
  collection.map do |k, v|
    v.each do |tag|
      results[tag.to_sym] ||= []
      results[tag.to_sym] << k unless results[tag.to_sym].include? k
    end

    if v.empty?
      results[nil] ||= []
      results[nil] << k unless results[nil].include? k
    end
  end

  results
```

Comment: Why `tag.to_sym`?

Answer (score 0):

Using [#enumerable#wit_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) with [Hash#new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-c-new)(*) to default empty array as object:

```
res = collection.each_with_object(Hash.new([])) do |(obj, tags), h|
  tags.each { |tag| h[tag] += [obj] }
  h[nil] += [obj] if tags.empty?
end
```

> (*) If obj is specified, this single object will be used for all default values.